# Interstitial ad displaying while app is in background

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I have a interstitial ad set up to show after 5 minutes, however I do not want it to open unless the user is viewing the app. There is a issue in testing where if you go to another app, it will still pop up over it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave the application (home button, etc), you need to clear the AdListener in `onPause()` callback.

Assuming that you've set the adListener in your `adView`, you may set his listener to null when android call `onPause`. It would be something like this:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(adView != null) {
        adView.setAdListener(null);
    }
}
```

I don't know what version of admob you're using, but this should work with Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

it is how it works that the ads should not displayed after it is in background.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```